# Use of xparse macro and expl3 key-value pairs

Tags: expl3, xparse, key-value

I'm trying to set up a family of key-pairs to be used in a `\NewDocumentCommand`. The goal is to have a function with two key-pairs. I want to be able to get the values of the two keys within the macro, similarly to using #1, #2.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{    \usetheme{metropolis}    }

\geometry{verbose,papersize={160mm,90mm}}
\usepackage{tikz,xkeyval}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\makeatletter
\define@key{mykeyset}{testingkey}{#1}
\presetkeys{mykeyset} {testingkey} {testingkey={testingkey~default~value}}
\define@key{mykeyset}{secondkey}{#1}
\presetkeys{mykeyset}{secondkey}{secondkey={secondkey~default~value}}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\ifelsetest{ m o }{
  optional~parameter~:~#2
  \par
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
  { \setkeys{mykeyset}{secondkey={secondkey~default~value~set~by~macro}} }
  { \setkeys{mykeyset}{#2} }

%here trying to print independently the values alone of the keys
  \mykeyset@testingkey  
  \mykeyset@secondkey
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\ifelsetest{test} % #2 should be -NoValue-
\par
\ifelsetest{test}[]
\par
\ifelsetest{test}[testingkey=shouldtesttrue]
\par
\ifelsetest{test}[testingkey=]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

EDIT : following the comments, here is a try using `expl3`.
Also I changed "`xkeyval`" by "`expl3` key-value pairs" in the title.

The key value is ending up in a boolean value by taking the string `yes` as True, and whatever else, including empty string as `False`.

Actually I would like to add a lot of possibilities that could be issued through the key and ending up in either `True` or `False`.

For example for `True` : "yes", "ok", "go head", ...
and for `False` : "no", "stop", "don't do it", ...

Though I could issue a `\tl_if_in:NnTF` for each of these words, is there any shorter option?

EDIT : as per suggestion i added a clist to allow for several options to set the boolean to `True`
i used `\clist_if_in:NnTF` but I'd need a \clist_if_in:NNTF`. Because` \clist_if_in:NnTF` expects a list as its second argument i had to use \tl_use:N.

It does not work and there are weird things in the NiceTabular (comma at the beginning of the content in the first column)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{    \usetheme{metropolis}    }

\geometry{verbose,papersize={160mm,90mm}}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn {groupetest/textbloc }
{
  clef .tl_set:N = \l_groupetest_clef_tl
}

\bool_new:N \l_clef_bool
\clist_new:N \l_istrue_clist
\clist_set:Nn \l_istrue_clist { {yes} , {oui} , {ok} , {dac} , {go~head} , {yup} , {super} }

\NewDocumentCommand\textbloc{ O{} }{
  \keys_set:nn { groupetest/textbloc } { #1 }

  \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_groupetest_clef_tl
     {
       \bool_set_false:N \l_clef_bool
     }

% here using \clist_if_in:NnTF, but why is there
% no \clist_if_in:NNTF ??
     {
       \clist_if_in:NnTF \l_istrue_clist 
                    { \tl_use:N \l_groupetest_clef_tl }
         {
           \bool_set_true:N \l_clef_bool
         }
         {
           \bool_set_false:N \l_clef_bool
         }
     }
     
  \bool_if:NTF \l_clef_bool
    {
      clé~'clef'~=~\l_groupetest_clef_tl & var.~bool~'clef'~: True \\
    }
    {
      clé~'clef'~=~\l_groupetest_clef_tl & var.~bool~'clef'~: False \\
    }

  \keys_set:nn { groupetest/textbloc }
    { clef={} }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ll}[hvlines]
\textbloc[clef=abc]  
\textbloc[clef=yes]  
\textbloc  
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here it is:

https://imgur.com/yzYb80b.png
[screenshot](https://imgur.com/yzYb80b.png)

Comment: you need `\makeatletter` as you have `\mykeyset@testingkey ` (you don't need `\ExplSyntaxOn` as you have no L3 code) so move `\makeatother`  down

Comment: `expl3` has a full-fledged key-value system. Don't mix `xkeyval` with `expl3`.

Comment: You could define a set of values and test whether the value passed to the key is in that set. You could use a `clist` that way, for example. But this feels as though we're straying towards XY-problem territory ...?

Comment: I think it would be easier to answer that if you gave a bit more info on what you're trying to achieve, in it's current form this is really a strange question... Just for the `clist` test: Use `\clist_if_in:NVTF \l_istrue_clist \l_groupetest_clef_tl {<true>} {<false>}` instead.

Comment: Just to elaborate a bit on my former comment: Currently you show two different code blocks with pretty different results and behaviour. Unless we know what you intend to achieve, I could provide a nicer way to achieve the first, and a more clean way to implement the second. But the two MWEs have almost no intersection it seems to me.

Comment: initially it was a matter of setting up an example with two key-pairs. In the update i wanted that this example allows many possibilities for users to mean `True` and similarly for `False`. I actually found the solution (use of `\clist_if_:NVTF ...` as you suggested) soon after my update and forgot this post.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would've originally needed more focus, but in the meantime OP found a solution to the original problem, and the question seems of little value for future visitors.